# how to set internet explorer security settings from command prompt

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, cmd

I need to set IE security settings from command prompt

for example I need to customize Custom Level settings

I need to UN-check "Launching Applications and Unsafe Files" through command prompt.

[image: IE-Settings]

Comment: This question seems not to be about programming, maybe this should be migrated to [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /v "1806" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569). Old but useful

Comment: Thank you its very  helpful,if i want to switch to other zones like Local Intranet,Trusted sites etc then how is it possible

Comment: See linked page. Change zone number as needed.

Comment: yeah got all zones and final question i need to enable protected mode and my task will be done

Comment: 2500 in the linked list. 0 = Enabled, 3 = Disabled