# change security level of a zone in Internet Properties for IE windows 10 powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

[image]

I want to change the slider's position or security level for a zone through Powershell. I'm able to get zone but can't find how to change/move the slider.
I'm trying this
`Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1" -Name 1A10 -Value 0`
to lower the security level but unable to do so.

I've tried [how to set internet explorer security settings from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323569/how-to-set-internet-explorer-security-settings-from-command-prompt)
and
[IE Browser - Powershell script to add site to trusted sites list, disable protected mode & make all zones security level low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720030/ie-browser-powershell-script-to-add-site-to-trusted-sites-list-disable-protec)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be recommended to make this change using GPO rather than a script.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I need to automate this task using the user's input. Please, help me to achieve this task? any resources or links would be appreciated